# Will I be able to travel from Ireland to France if I'm negative for COVID-19 but don't have a vaccine?

Tags: covid-19, security

I'm planning on travelling to Nice, France at the end of July/start of August. The vaccine roll-out by the Irish government is slow and although my family member who is 40 has gotten vaccinated, it seems unlikely that I will (22) until the middle of the summer at the least.

Do I need a vaccine to travel to France and within Europe or just a negative test result?

Comment: Ireland is planing to implement the *Digital Green Certificate* where a full vaccinated person is considered equivalent to a negative PCR-Test. Proof of Vaccination or the PCR-Test result will remain as sufficient proof, but having the Certificate (mainly the QR-Code in digital or paper form) will make things simpler since the only the QR-Code needs to be read to varify your status in Hotels, Restaurants and other public places.

Comment: @MarkJohnson There is absolutely no agreement that this is how these certificates are going to work. I already pointed you to the relevant plans from the EU commission. Last I checked, they were still pushing for some harmonisation but the basic logic of the system is that the *destination* country sets the rules. It's not up to Ireland to decide whether a PCR test is equivalent to a vaccine, what the Irish government will do is vouch for what a person got and the destination country can use that to enforce their own rules.

Comment: The French government is also wavering about regulations for restaurants. This has been hotly debated and there is no official plan to make entry contingent on presenting a certificate.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid crystal balls are in short supply these days. I'm not sure anyone can predict what, if anything, you will need to enter France from Ireland in 2 months.

It could range from "you can come as you wish" to "whatever your status you can't enter France without an imperious motive and you have to quarantine for 10 days", with "you need to be vaccinated" or "a negative PCR test is enough" in between.

The **current situation** is that you can enter France with just a recent PCR test (and a sworn declaration that you don't have symptoms, haven't been in contact with a confirmed case and that you accept a test on arrival), and vaccines actually currently don't exempt you from that requirement.

**Current** details are here: https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Certificate-of-international-travel#from2

The **current plan** is to allow fully vaccinated persons to enter without the PCR test.

Note that this can change very quickly, as it has happened multiple times, most recently with additional restrictions for the UK due to the spread of the Indian variant there.

Answer (score 3):

For the last year and a half, it has almost always been possible to enter France from the EU. Since last summer, the only times when entry was effectively restricted is when France itself was under lockdown and domestic travel was also severly curtailed. Many other restrictions have applied to people coming from countries *outside* the EU but not on people travelling within the EU, and the government has signaled its intent to find ways to support the tourism industry and facilitates visits from abroad, even from outside the EU.

Save for a dramatic flare up of some new variant or something similar, it therefore seems unlikely that it would become mandatory to be vaccinated to enter France. The question would then become whether it would spare you the PCR test or any possible quarantine requirement but that's hard to tell with any certainty.